# Salesforce Opportunity -> Custom Object

Tags: administration, custom-object

I'm trying to find a way to convert a Salesforce Opportunity into a Custom Object (termed "Projects" in this specific instance of Salesforce)

I would want to transfer data over from the opportunity to the custom object, and allow for editing in the new location, without affecting the old (though if it does affect the old, this is not necessarily a deal breaker).

I've been reading about how there are crossover object formulas, and custom buttons - but I'm not really seeing any sources on them, or what to use in this particular case.

I can't use Apex - I only have access to the professional version.

What's the most elegant solution to solving this problem?

Comment: Can you use the DataLoader ? You can extract Opportunity records, set up a mapping to the fields in the custom object and data load the rows in.

Comment: No, this is to be a continuous ongoing process.

Answer (score 1):

Url parameters are the only way from my understanding

This should get you started
http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html

Comment: There is a length limit to a URL, so you can only use that for so many fields before exceeding the length (essentially 2000 characters - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)